# Errors about text (>) in tag (<jsp:directive.page>): Invalid location of text (>) and expected '>'

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I wrote a simple JSP file:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" session=”true” isErrorPage=”false”%> 
<HTML> 
<BODY> 
<h4>Welcome to the world of JSP</h4> 

This JSP uses the page directive 
</BODY> 
</HTML>
```

I got error for the first line, inside Eclipse:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Invalid location of text (>) in tag (<jsp:directive.page>).
    - Start tag (<jsp:directive.page>) not closed properly, expected 
     '>'.
```

- Regarding the first message in the error,  the first line `<%@ page import="java.util.*" session=”true” isErrorPage=”false”%>` doesn't seem to have a  `>` with invalid location. What does the error message mean?
- Regarding the second message in the error, isn't the `<%@ page import="java.util.*" session=”true” isErrorPage=”false”%>` ended with `>`? Why does it say `>` is expected?

Thanks.

Comment: Quotes in session="true" and isErrorPage look strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your tag

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" session=”true” isErrorPage=”false”%>
```

these are not the usual double quotes, change that with

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" session="true" isErrorPage="false"%>
```